# Cleaning up the Garbage Output File

Tags: python-3.x, io

I am pretty new to Python and tried to read a jpg file and write it as a simple practice. The file was not huge, only 142 KBytes but when I used the buffer chunks of 50000 Bytes to read and write it to a new.jpg file, it gave limited space error and ate up all of my remaining 4GB of space in the C:\ drive on my desktop and never released that memory. How can I see and free up the memory used by Python. Here is my code:

```
def main():

    buffersize = 50000                  
    infile = open('olives.jpg', 'rb')   
    outfile = open('new.jpg', 'wb')
    buffer = infile.read(buffersize)
    while(len(buffer)):
        outfile.write(buffer)
        print('.', end = '')
        infile.read(buffersize)
    print()
    print('Done')

if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```

Please let me know how I can free this memory as my C:\ Drive is short in memory.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your loop, you never change `buffer`. You need to assign the `read` result, or you just keep writing the same original `buffer` contents over and over, the loop never ends. Change the final line of this `while` loop:

```
while(len(buffer)):
    outfile.write(buffer)
    print('.', end = '')
    infile.read(buffersize) # <-- Not assigning result
```

to:

```
    buffer = infile.read(buffersize)
```

Also, for style points, change `while(len(buffer)):` to just `while buffer:`; `bytes` objects (like all sequences) are truthy when non-zero length, and falsy when zero-length (and Python doesn't require parens for conditional statements unless they're needed for something like grouping tests).

As for "freeing the memory" (meaning "cleaning up the garbage output file"), just delete it. At the command line, you can just visit the working directory you ran the script in and run `del new.jpg`, or navigate there the same way in the file browser. If you have no idea where the file is, rerunning your script after fixing the infinite loop problem will truncate the original file before writing to it (because your mode included `w`), which will also solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you so much ShadowRanger. It was very helpful.

Comment: @Saeed: You're welcome. FYI, if this solved your problem, you can up-vote and/or accept the answer (see the checkmark and arrows to the left of the answer, near the top of the answer).

Comment: I just did it. I did not know how to accept. However, for voting I need at least 15 reputations to vote. I tried voting yesterday as well but could not do it.

Comment: @Saeed: Learn something new every day (I built a little rep years ago, and only returned to SO last year, so I didn't remember the constraint). Thanks.